# Is there a way to identify duplicated rows based on partial text/string?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, nltk

I am trying to flag the duplicated item based on partial text/string. For example, I have a dataset like below, the description for inventory 1 both contain the text of "Sales number decrease", where inventory 2 both contain the text of "sales number increased". The desired output is to create a "duplicate" column and flag these records as "Y".

Is there any partial string matching approach or any other approach that can achieve this result? Be noted the below is a fake and simplified dataset to present my idea. In my read dataset, I have over thousand rows and some texts are in the middle of the sentence with upper vs lower case as well as present over past tense. I want to explore some ideas. Thanks.

Below is the code

```
import pandas as pd
df1 = { 'item':['item1','item2','item3','item4','item5','item6'],
  'name':['inventory1','inventory1','inventory2','inventory2','inventory3','inventory3'],
  'code':[1,1,2,2,3,3],
  'description':['sales number decrease compared to last month', 'Sales number 
  decreased','sales number increased','Sales number increased, need to keep kpi','no sales 
  this month','item out of stock']}


df1=pd.DataFrame(df1)
```

The desired output is like below:
[image]

Comment: You'll need to 1) use a [text similarity metric](https://towardsdatascience.com/overview-of-text-similarity-metrics-3397c4601f50) and 2) apply it to every row pair combination.

Comment: Can't you do it in two steps? First use Series.str.extract to create a new column with just the phrases you're looking for, then check for duplicates in the new column?

Comment: @Linden, can you clarify your idea? Separately, there is no specific phrases I am looking for. The description is random text input by different sales teams. Also the pair does not always have 2 rows, there are 3 rows, 4 rows or even 5 rows for each pair which makes it impossible for me to achieve the goal.

Comment: Sorry, my idea was identifying duplicates based on extracting specific phrases (i.e. "sales number increase" and "sales number decrease"). Maybe you're looking for something like FuzzyWuzzy  (https://pypi.org/project/fuzzywuzzy/)